# What are the differences between values: ADMIN, USER, SUPERUSER for management.security.roles for spring boot applications?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I found no documentation for management.security.roles configuration. What are the actual differences between these valuse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just examples, there's nothing specific in Spring Boot about these.

The only thing is that the management security role defaults to `ADMIN`. So if your user happen to have that role, then you'll be able to access the secured actuator endpoints. You can change that value to anything you want and that's where the `SUPERUSER` role came from (it's just an example).

Comment: Thank you for answering.@Stephane Nicoll